# Arcpy addin editable textbox on tool bar

Tags: python, arcpy, arcmap, python-addin

I would like to add an editable toolbox on an arcpy addin toolbar.  This would be used to change values of a threshold but I don't think this is currently available. (What I would really like is a slider!)

My current work around is to use a combobox which does 80% of what I want it to do except display an initial value and update the displayed value when altered programatically. As can be seen in my code I have a + and - button that can change the value stored in the combo box `items` variable.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import os

class decreaseBottom(object):
    """Implementation for alterRange.btn1 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        firstBreak.items[0] -= 1
        if firstBreak.items[0] < 0:
            firstBreak.items[0] = 0
        firstBreak.refresh()

class decreaseTop(object):
    """Implementation for alterRange.btn3 (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        firstBreak.items[0] += 1
        if firstBreak.items[0] > 100:
            firstBreak.items[0] = 100
        firstBreak.refresh()

class firstBreak(object):
    """Implementation for alterRange.firstBreak (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = [30]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
    def onSelChange(self, selection):
        pass
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        pass
    def onFocus(self, focused):
        pass
    def onEnter(self):
        pass
    def refresh(self):
        pass
```

Is there a variable in the `__init__` of the combo box that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.value = 30
```

will set the initial value of the combobox to 30.

Updating the displayed value from your buttons is similar, in this case:

```
firstBreak.value = firstBreak.items[0]
```

before your combobox refresh should do the trick.

You don't seem to be using the dropdown or editing functionality of the combobox, so you could consider setting `self.editable = False` on your combobox. You may not even need to set .items in this case, simply setting and modifying .value might work, but I haven't tested that.